# warning: implicit declaration of function 'kill'

Tags: c, kill

I am making these inclusions:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
```

But still getting this warning.

Comment: If the way you're calling kill doesn't match the actual prototype, then that could be the reason you're seeing this warning.

Comment: Feature test macro requirements `_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 1 || _XOPEN_SOURCE || _POSIX_SOURCE` ?

Comment: On linux kernel with ubuntu 10.10

Comment: Its says: _i'_POSIX_C_SOURCE undelcared', first use this function._

Comment: I'm using gcc 4.2.4 in Ubuntu and it doesn't gives me any warning. Maybe is the way you are calling `kill`. Put the portion of code where you call it.

Answer (score 12):

You are probably passing the "-ansi -Wall" switches to the gcc compiler.
You can remove "-ansi" if you don't need it, otherwise try to set the proper feature define macro.

Something like:

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
```

Comment: still getting this error, I call it passing it's parameters : (int signal, void (*handler) (int)), with handler pointer to a function returning void and accepting an int like parameter.

Comment: Order matters. The line "#define _POSIX_SOURCE" should be your first line in the file, or before your first include.

Comment: but my source is with _BSD_SOURCE. Does that mean that I cannot use the system call kill() ? weird!

Answer (score 3):

You can also define it on the compile time by adding this flag with gcc.

```
-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE
```

ex:

```
-g -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE -Wall -std=c99
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the kill(2) Linux manual page, `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` must be `#define`d before any includes in order for the prototype of the function kill() to be included through `<signal.h>` if you are using glibc.

Your code will probably compile either way, since the binary is available for linking regardless of the defines, but that's the proper way to silence this warning according to the documentation.