# Linux/gcc and kill()

Tags: linux, gcc, kill

I'm compiling a piece of C code that references/calls kill(pid,SIGNAL).

The code includes:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
```

When I compile using gcc, I get:
"warning: implicit declaration of function ‘kill’ "

When I compile using g++, no complaints.

Why?

Comment: Show the call to `kill`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [warning: implicit declaration of function 'kill'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994530/warning-implicit-declaration-of-function-kill)

Comment: You need to at least show how you compile this, the verbatim command that you're running in both cases. Preferably show a minimal test case that others can compile too.